# Можно ли отправить email абсолютно анонимно, чтобы отправителя невозможно было вычислить?

Tags: email

Возможно ли это с точки зрения самого протокола SMTP?

Comment: http://dropmail.me

Answer (score 1):

Используя анонимное соединение. Например, с помощью анонимного браузера Tor. Можно зарегистрировать новый e-mail ящик, или же использовать сайт для анонимной отправки письма, их сейчас полно в интернете, вот один из них например: [anonymouse.org](http://anonymouse.org)

Comment: Главное, что бы на этих серверах не было логов:)

Comment: На сайте на который я дал ссылку они не ведутся http://anonymouse.org/privacy.html

Comment: Как говорил Ленин, можно верить всему, что видишь в интернете.

Comment: @Abmin,  у меня, к примеру, этот сайт вообще блокируется провайдером

Comment: @koks_rs, скачай себе браузер Тоr

Comment: @KoVadim, полностью с вами согласен.